# Have you done take-home robotics(ROS) coding test in interviews?

Tags: ros

Have you done take-home robotics(ROS) coding test in interviews?

Do you want to share the coding test instructions with me? or point me in the right direction where I can find some to practice?

I'm looking for something similar to this:

https://github.com/andrestoga/take_home_robotics_coding_test

. Those are the tests I've done so far.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics*, andrestoga. I'm not sure I understand your question - you were given some coding tests, and now you're looking for coding tests? Or you were given coding tests and you want solutions? Please *edit your question* to clarify the *specific, answerable question* you have, what work you've done so far to solve the problem, and what you need help with.

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for coding tests instructions to practice. I'm not looking for their solutions. I'll edit the question accordingly.